# How to check app version from web

Tags: javascript, ios

Hi i have native ios app

And i have old version that not compitible with this site

I want from my site to check the app version ? Is it Possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making a call from the app to your web service, you should be including the app's version in the request.  This versioning allows your server to respond appropriately to each request.

If you have existing, deployed versions sending unversioned requests, then you can't really go back and make them send their version.  However, your web service does know that if a request didn't specify a version, that it was sent from a version prior to the version in which you began versioned requests.

Furthermore, if the structure of the requests have changed, which may be your case, that itself provides a hint as to the requesting version.

Comment: Even simpler, you could add the bundle identifier and the bundle version within the user agent http-header request variable. Actually, ASIHTTPRequest and NSURLConnection do that automagically for you.